# Why can't install harbor from Rancher server catalog?

Tags: docker, rancher, harbor

Using new version of rancher server. One master node and two agent nodes.

When install Harbor from catalog, the services got all unhealthy, why?

[image]
All the config were using default options before lunch it:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says:

> Allocation failed: needs host with label harbor-host: true

Does at least one of the hosts have a host label of `harbor-host` that is set to `true`?

See http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/hosts/#host-labels for more information. You can navigate to the hosts section in the UI and edit an individual host to set labels on it.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't set any host label yet. That's the reason. Also thanks to your link.